# My car has bright headlights. How to prevent other drivers from flashing their brights at me?

Tags: headlight

I have a car with those very bright LED headlights. Often when I am driving at night, other drivers flash their brights at me because they believe I have left my brights on. Sometimes they get really obnoxious about it and flash multiple times. I usually flash my brights in return and hope they feel a little stupid, but it starts to wear on me after the, say, fifth time it happens in a single drive.

Short of replacing the LED bulbs with dimmer lights (which I don't think is possible in my car anyway), is there any way to prevent other drivers from flashing me with their brights in the first place?

Comment: Have you had your alignment checked (do you carry heavy stuff?) - you could be blinding the other drivers and they, rightfully, are upset...

Comment: @SolarMike The heaviest thing I carry are passengers, typically just one who sits in the front seat. I haven't had the alignment checked but I could ask about that.

Comment: If you want to dim your lights without changing your LED's you can use polarizers.

Answer (score 3):

Can you please clarify? Are they sealed LED headlamp units or are they LED bulbs inside halogen headlamp housings?

If they are LED bulbs inside halogen headlamps, then they are not DOT approved, as such a product doesn't exist. Such bulbs don't project correctly and result in people being blinded.

Comment: It is also possible that the headlights on the OP's car are misaligned, or that the OP is carrying weight in the back seat or trunk that causes the car's front end to look up, or that the rear springs on the car are sacked and thus shorter than stock.

Comment: It is true. I apologize for assuming too much. It would be nice to find out more details about OP's lighting setup.

Comment: Naseldov No need to apologize; your Answer was correct as putting LEDs inside a housing built for halogen bulbs is a common modification, which — as you observe — often blinds oncoming traffice. I merely noted other possible causes.

Comment: Just to note that asking for clarification is done in comments not answers, but that comes with a bit more rep... So, keep going and enjoy, PS I've added to your total...

Comment: @MishaNasledov They came standard on the car when I purchased it new from the dealer two years ago. I just use the car for commuting, never carrying or hauling anything larger than a few passengers. I don't think it's even possible to replace them with halogen bulbs because I doubt they make a bulb that fits.

Comment: @lizziv headlight bulbs come in several types, H3 and H4 being 2 common ones and LED ones are made to match those fittings... so until you know exactly what is fitted to your car you cannot be sure if there are, or are not, any other bulbs available to fit your car....

Comment: @lizziv If your car is equipped with factory LED lights, then those lights are part of the assembly and are indeed not replaceable without replacing the entire assembly.

It sounds like you are using all the factory equipped lighting -- in this case, the questions other folks have asked about whether you have a lot of cargo in the back of your car become more relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Adjust them so they're a little more dipped since you can afford to do that as you've more light than what's necessary for someone who isn't blind